# removing carriage returns from csv using python

Tags: python, csv, carriage-return

I'm trying to remove carriage returns from a large csv file while importing using deletechars = '/r' in np.genfromtxt but it's not doing the trick. A bit new to python so I figure this is the wrong approach.

the input csv file looks something like this: time, id1, id2, amount, message 
2015-11-02 08:38:53, 49446, 6289, 13.74,  
2015-11-02 08:38:53, 52359, 8352, 27.10,
2015-11-02 08:38:53, 31639, 2462, 18.68,  
2015-11-02 08:38:53, 14381, 15167, 20.92, For your share. 
2015-11-02 08:38:53, 17952, 6789, 39.09,  
2015-11-02 08:38:53, 54708, 18138, 21.74,  
2015-11-02 08:38:53, 74080, 48140, 36.92, Food '\r' And rent 
2015-11-02 08:38:53, 46792, 8134, 32.07, Juice

etc.

and i'm trying to read the file with this: batch_id1, batch_id2 = np.genfromtxt("pay.csv",delimiter=',', dtype='str',skip_header=0, deletechars='\r', autostrip=True, replace_space=True, filling_values='NA',usecols=(1,2))

and the errors i'm getting are this: in genfromtxt raise ValueError(errmsg) ValueError: Some errors were detected ! Line #411567 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #411568 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #411569 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #411570 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #411571 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #411572 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #620094 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #620095 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #620096 (got 1 columns instead of 2) Line #620097 (got 1 columns instead of 2) – OsloS 26 mins ago

Comment: do you mean `\r`, not `/r`.

Comment: yes, sorry that was a typo in this post.

Comment: Different system (Windows, Linux, Mac) may use different "newline" - `\r` , `\n` or `\r\n`. If you use Windows then you can have `\r\n` and you remove `\r` but you still have `\n` in line. Python use `\n` to recognize all types of `newline`. You have to show file and example code so we could test it.

Comment: add all information to question.